# Example is required

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, continuity

I am trying to find a seuqence of a continuous functions  $\{f_n\}$ defined on $[0,1]$ bounded by some small number, say $\varepsilon$ with the additional requirement of $f_n^\prime(t_0)=1$ at a particular point $t_0\in [0,1]$. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Try $$f_n(t)=\epsilon\arctan\frac{t-t_0}\epsilon$$
or simply
$$ f_n(t)=\min\{\epsilon,\max\{-\epsilon,t-t_0\}\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Choose $t_1,t_2$ such that $\frac{t_2-t_1}{2}=\varepsilon$ and $t_0=t_1+\frac{t_2-t_1}{4}$. Define $t_3=\frac{t_1+t_2}{2}$. Then define your function to be $\max \{ 0,\varepsilon-|t-t_3| \}$. (In effect I have drawn a triangle of height $\varepsilon$ and width $1/\varepsilon$, and put $t_0$ on the left half of the triangle.)